# Android AlertDialog remembers string from previous shown?

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

The problem I am having with my Alert dialog is that,  I have a custom dialog which has 3 edittext end 3 textview on it. when I pick up a contact from contacts I just filled the information in the dilaog edtitext like contactName.setText(bla); however the strange thing happens here that if I cancel the dialog and again pick another contact the details on the dialog is not getting changed and remembers the details from the first picked contact? is int weird? it seems that once it creates the dialog even though if I call the same process creating again the dialog it keeps the first dialog and keeps showing the same dialog. is there anyone whom have had the same experience and know how to solve this?

Here is the code that handles the result comes back from the contact picker.

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                switch (requestCode) {
                case CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT:
                    Cursor cursor = null;
                    String email = "";
                    try {
                        Uri result = data.getData();
                        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Got a contact result: "
                                + result.toString());

                        // get the contact id from the Uri
                        String id = result.getLastPathSegment();

                        // query for everything email
                        cursor = getContentResolver().query(Email.CONTENT_URI,
                                null, Email.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { id },
                                null);

                        int emailIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA);

                        // let's just get the first email
                        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                            email = cursor.getString(emailIdx);
                            contactUEmail=email;
                            Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Got email: " + email);
                        } else {
                            Log.w(DEBUG_TAG, "No results");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Failed to get email data", e);
                    } finally {
                        if (cursor != null) {
                            cursor.close();
                        }
                      //  EditText emailEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.invite_email);
                      //  emailEntry.setText(email);
                        if (email.length() == 0) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "No email found for contact.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }

                    showDialog(DIALOG_ADD_NEW_CALL);// this is where I call the dialog.
                    break;
                }

            } else {
                Log.w(DEBUG_TAG, "Warning: activity result not ok");
            }
        }
```

and here is the dialog DIALOG_ADD_NEW_CALL;

```
case DIALOG_ADD_NEW_CALL:
        {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        entryView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.entry, null);
        builder.setView(entryView);
        CNameEditor = (EditText) entryView.findViewById(R.id.cName);
        CEmailEditor = (EditText) entryView.findViewById(R.id.cEmail);
        CPhoneEditor = (EditText) entryView.findViewById(R.id.cPhone);

        if(!contactUEmail.equals(""))//here is the code that I am setting the text.
        CEmailEditor.setText(contactUEmail);
        else{}

        builder.setTitle(R.string.addDialogTitle);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.addItem,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }   
                });

        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancelItem,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        dialog.cancel();

                    }
                }).create();

        return builder.create();

        }
```

Comment: Some code would be awsome. This could be anything. Sounds like you just set the values once. Any chance you have a check if value set don't set them again or something like that? Or if the view allready has been inflated don't do it again? Please provide something more :)

Comment: Unless you show the code you're using it's difficult for anyone to give an answer.

Comment: I have just edited and put the code there. I hope you will be able to see the mistake which I making :) it is really annoying. I spent half of the day to solve this and still the same:)

Comment: maybe I should set the view after setting the edittext?

Comment: I put Log.i in the DIALOG_ADD_NEW_CALL and it is called only first time as I can see. the rest when ever i bring up the dialog it doesnt run the code again?  how can I destroy the dialog and create it again everytime with the new data?

Answer (score 1):

To destroy the dialog, you can call [`removeDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#removeDialog%28int%29). Alternatively, you could override [`onPrepareDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareDialog%28int,%20android.app.Dialog,%20android.os.Bundle%29) and update the dialog before it's shown. Just FYI, both methods are deprecated in favor of [`DialogFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) along with [`FragmentManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) but you probably have to redo a lot of code to use those.

Answer (score 0):

Override `onPrepareDialog`

```
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_ADD_NEW_CALL:
        AlertDialog callDialog = (AlertDialog) dialog;
        View entryView = callDialog;
        CNameEditor = (EditText) entryView.findViewById(R.id.cName);
        CEmailEditor = (EditText) entryView.findViewById(R.id.cEmail);
        CPhoneEditor = (EditText) entryView.findViewById(R.id.cPhone);
        // do stuff to those variables here
    }
}
```